# NSScanner scanCharactersFromSet fails to find leading tabs

Tags: xcode, cocoa

A simple routine to find the number of leading tabs using NSScanner, except it finds none of the tabs. The code goes to the 'else' of the scanCharactersFromSet statement. I tried changing asciiTabRange.location to be 0x49 (ASCII 'I'), and changed the input string to start with 'I' instead of tab, and it will find a leading 'I', so the problem seems specific to leading tabs. The lldb output shows the string starts with a tab, and the [asciiTab characterIsMember] statement returns YES.

```
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    if ([recordString length] != 0) {
        NSScanner* theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: recordString];

        NSString* testConfirmString = [theScanner string];
        const char* testConfirmCStr = [testConfirmString cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        if (testConfirmCStr != NULL);

        NSRange asciiTabRange;
        asciiTabRange.location = 0x09;
        asciiTabRange.length   = 1;
        NSCharacterSet* asciiTab = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange: asciiTabRange];

        if ([asciiTab characterIsMember: 0x09] == YES) {
            testConfirmCStr = 0;
        }

        NSString*  tabString = nil;
        if ([theScanner scanCharactersFromSet: asciiTab
                                   intoString: &tabString] == YES) {
            tabLevel = [tabString length];
        } else {
            tabLevel = 0;
        }
        itemText = [recordString substringFromIndex: tabLevel];
    } else {
        // ?
    }
    children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
```

}

(lldb) x -c 32 testConfirmCStr
0x600000043a91: 09 49 6e 64 75 73 74 72 79 3a 09 54 65 73 74 53  .Industry:.TestS
0x600000043aa1: 65 76 65 72 61 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90  everal..........

Comment: Could you give an example of input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `NSScanner` ignores [whitespace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/whitespaceCharacterSet) and newlines; the whitespace character set includes the tab character (`U+0009`). Try removing this default:

```
NSScanner* theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: recordString];
theScanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil;
```

It's also worth being aware of the `NSScanner` property `scanLocation`, in simple cases this may help you count the actual tabs:

```
NSString *recordString = @"\t\t\tHello\t\tGoodbye\tHello";

NSScanner* theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: recordString];
theScanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil;

NSRange asciiTabRange;
asciiTabRange.location = 0x09;
asciiTabRange.length   = 1;
NSCharacterSet* asciiTab = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange: asciiTabRange];

NSString *tabString;
unsigned long indexOfFirstTabInRun = 0;
unsigned long tabsInRun = 0;

while (!theScanner.isAtEnd) {
    indexOfFirstTabInRun = (unsigned long)theScanner.scanLocation;
    if ([theScanner scanCharactersFromSet: asciiTab intoString: &tabString]) {
        tabsInRun = (unsigned long) theScanner.scanLocation - indexOfFirstTabInRun;
        NSLog(@"tabCount: %lu - starting at index %lu", tabsInRun, indexOfFirstTabInRun);
    } else {
        [theScanner scanCharactersFromSet:asciiTab.invertedSet intoString:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I did not know about the default set of skipped characters.

Comment: If the answer works for you, consider selecting it as the *accepted answer*.